# Cosa sono "le torbe" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Qui non succede niente di niente. E neppure a Braino, vedrete. E neppure in tutta quanta la zona fino quasi alla valle. Gli uomini sono ai pascoli, adesso, e non tornano prima di notte: qualcun altro sta verso **le torbe**, e le donne a far legna qua e là. Se vi affacciate un momento in strada, tutt’al piú riuscirete a trovare una vecchia a soffiar sul fornello.

Cercando il vocabolo "torba" nei dizionari ho trovato definizioni che fanno riferimento a un combustibile fossile o a un suolo costituito di sostanza organica. Tuttavia, queste accezioni mi sembrano un po' strane nel contesto del brano precedente, con "le torbe" così in plurale. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono "le torbe" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direi che l’autore per [torbe](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torbiera) voglia intendere torbiere, cioè

> ambienti caratterizzati da grande abbondanza di acqua (acquitrino o
>   palude) in movimento lento e a bassa temperatura. In tale ambiente si
>   sviluppa una vegetazione prevalentemente erbacea tipica di luoghi
>   umidi, briofite (muschi) ma anche Gramineae (graminacee), Cyperaceae
>   ed altre.
>
> In ambiente umido e freddo in presenza di consistenti quantità di
>   composti tannici e di sostanze acide, l'attività dei batteri che
>   naturalmente degradano la sostanza organica viene fortemente inibita,
>   per di più l'ambiente limoso e con scarsa circolazione di acqua e
>   quindi povero di ossigeno rende inospitale l'ambiente per i
>   microrganismi. Il materiale vegetale che deriva dal ciclo biologico
>   delle piante che vivono nella torbiera, tende quindi progressivamente
>   ad accumularsi in strati dando origine alla torba, unitamente a resti
>   di animali come gli insetti.

Nel passaggio da te indicato gli uomini si stanno dirigendo verso zone paludose.

Comment: Infatti, questo vocabolo, "le torbe", appare parecchie volte nel racconto. Ma parla anche delle "torbiere", come nel esempio del mio commento seguente.

Comment: «Viveva sola, al di là del sentiero degli olmi, proprio ai margini della parrocchia, e dopo non ci sono che forre **torbiere** e anche peggio, se pur peggio è possibile: c’era venuta a stare da poco, e senza dir niente a nessuno, venendo su dalle parti di Bobbio dove quattro anni prima i tedeschi avevano bruciato anche i sassi: si chiamava Zelinda Icci fu Primo: aveva compiuto i sessantatre l’otto agosto, e adesso lavava stracci e budella dalla mattina alla sera laggiú dal canale per qualcuno o qualcosa di un paese di valle dove c’era già qualche industria.»